# Test Flight - How long does it take to transfer an App to a device?

Tags: xcode, ios

I was playing around with Test Flight - to put a version on my colleagues phone took 24-48 hours while we were separated. Normally he would work beside me and I can just directly compile to the device with a cable.

IIRC before Test Flight was absorbed by Apple the process was virtually instantaneous now it seems there is a giant propagation delay and nobody is talking about the delay or there is little mention of how long the whole process should take.

Have I done something wrong on my part or is this just part of the process?

Answer (score 1):

I use Testflight OS X desktop app to upload a binary and it usually takes minutes for recipients to receive build notification emails.